R adding, maintaining, and changes values when summing rows
I am trying to add certain values of rows together for some columns, but either keep or change other columns. Let's say the data frame I have is this:
df <- data.frame(Name = c("Ashley","Ashley","Ben","Ben","Clark","Clark"),
             Measure_ID = c("Score_A","Score_B","Score_A","Score_B","Score_A","Score_B"),
             Predicted = c(8,5,7,7,9,6),
             Actual = c(2,3,7,3,6,10),
             Extra = c("No","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes"))

I want the output to look like this, where Predicted is added together for each Name, and Actual is added together for each Name, but the Measure_ID changes, and Extra stays the same for each Name:
df_out <- data.frame(Name = c("Ashley","Ben","Clark"),
                 Name = c("Score_A_B","Score_A_B","Score_A_B"),
                 Predicted = c(13,14,15),
                 Actual = c(5,10,16),
                 Extra = c("No","Yes","Yes"))

I've used this, but I'm missing a few of the other columns I would like, and am wondering if I can add to the command somehow to get everything I want in the final data:
df_try <- df %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarize(Judge1 = sum(Predicted),Judge2 = sum(Actual))


Looks like aggregate(cbind(Predicted, Actual)~Name, df, sum)?

If Extra is that simple, just hard-code:
df |>
  dplyr::summarise(
    Measure_ID = toString(sub("Score_", "", Measure_ID)),
    Predicted = sum(Predicted), 
    Actual = sum(Actual), 
    Extra = unique(Extra),
    .by = Name)

giving
    Name Measure_ID Predicted Actual Extra
1 Ashley       A, B        13      5    No
2    Ben       A, B        14     10   Yes
3  Clark       A, B        15     16   Yes


Probably you can try
df %>%
  summarise(
    Measure_ID = str_remove(str_c(Measure_ID, collapse = "_"), "_Score"),
    Predicted = sum(Predicted),
    Actual = sum(Actual),
    .by = c(Name, Extra)
  ) %>%
  select(names(df))

which gives
    Name Measure_ID Predicted Actual Extra
1 Ashley  Score_A_B        13      5    No
2    Ben  Score_A_B        14     10   Yes
3  Clark  Score_A_B        15     16   Yes


@Friede no need to say sorry, please keep yours at it is
